# Form border color and thickness on Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

XE5, I am using the MetropolisUIBlue style in this case (not the app template just the style) and I would like to get the same effect that office 2013, where you have a very thin application form border, the title bar is there with the standard icons (close, minimize) with everything following the same form background color.

The result in office 2013 is very nice presentation (for me), that looks visually 
clean and light. and you still have the border to resize the form. This border is just 
a simple thin black line around the form and the windows theme selected does not interfere.

Right now by default Firemonkey has a dark huge border frame that follows windows theme. (I am  in windows 8)

How can I have the color following the same form background color?
How can I reduce to minimum (if possible just a thin line) the form border?
How can I block windows to apply its themes on the form border?

Comment: This is called non-client area stying. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719749/how-do-you-style-the-non-client-area-in-a-firemonkey-fm2-application-in-delphi-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on the top of the question there is a generic answer for this question.

There is a need of the style **windowborderstyle** be present and all these descendant stuff.

However the Firemonley Styles MetropolisUI that comes with Delphi XE2 - XE5 do not have that style defined.

If you take a look using the Style Editor, it is possible to load the VCL style for MetropolisUI, those contains this style, but are different in some ways with the Firemonkey correspondent.

What I did (since I have no idea and the lack of documentation):

- I have converted the VCL style to Firemoneky.
- On the form´s StyleBook I have loaded the above style
- then I have ADDED on the StyleBook the Firemonkey correspondent one (remember there the Blue, Dark, Black)

Doing this you get the windowborderstyle tag loaded with its dependencies, and the addition of Firemonkey style will correct the other styles overriding the previous ones.

The VCL MetropolisUI styles are simpler and does not have all those buttons and panels styles that is the cool part of using the style.