# Styling macOS form border (non-client area)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have an FMX application that implements a custom form toolbar for Windows.

This uses the idea discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12738601/9098350) of defining a `windowborderstyle` element in a `StyleBook`.

This works great. However I'm trying to implement the same idea for macOS, but the `windowborderstyle` element I currently use for Windows doesn't work for macOS.

I had the idea of downloading an FMX Style on GetIt provided by Embarcadero and trying that, thinking it might change the form border style on macOS (I downloaded Polar Dark). The windows style for this theme also defines a `windowborderstyle` element and changes the look of the form toolbar. The macOS style file doesn't, the default toolbar is displayed.

I'm assuming what I'm trying to do should be possible as there are apps on macOS that have a custom toolbar, like the System Preferences application for example

[image]

But maybe these applications are special cases. Interested to know if anyone has been able to do this or knows if this is possible.

Using Delphi 11.2

Comment: It looks like the app in question (System Preferences?) is using a toolbar. I have a demo for that [here](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/macOSToolbar). This was done pre macOS 11, so I'd need to expand the implementation to include things like the [search box](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssearchtoolbaritem?language=objc)

Comment: @DaveNottage Thank you, that's great! Being able to have a search box would be great, but being able to put my own buttons on there is already very nice. Going to experiment with this and see how it works.